# FileNotFoundError with multiprocessing

Tags: python

Hello I want to use multiprocessing inside a blender script, but for some reason I get a FileNotFoundError

```
def foo(a,b):
    print(a+b)

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo,args=[1,1])   
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo,args=[2,2])
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

I tried using concurrent.futures as well and got the same error.
Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: AFAIK multiprocessing is not really supported. You can open several instances of blender using the command line though

Comment: according to the docs, multiprocessing is supported "the subprocess and multiprocess modules can be used with Blender to make use of multiple CPUs too." 
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-using-threading-module

Comment: Yes, outside of Blender. If you read carefully the paragraphs just a bit higher from your quote the doc states this behaviour is unsupported and that it won't speed up your script.